# Rubocop disable all rules and create a whilelist of enabled rules

Tags: ruby, rubocop

I want to configure rubocop so it has no rules enabled and then create a list of the rules I do want enabled. I had a look a the rubocop docs but only found ways to disable individual rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're adding rubocop to an existing project a powerful soluion is to run

```
rubocop --auto-gen-config
```

This auto-generates a rubocop.todo.yml with all the current offending cops disabled with the most useful specificity. This way over time you can remove the disabled cops in the `todo` file and incrementally improve your code quality as and when appropriate.

Answer (score 8):

I think, that feature was realized for [this issue](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/rubocop/issues/1918).

All what you need:

```
# .rubocop.yml

AllCops:
  DisabledByDefault: true
```

Now, when you run rubocop, it will returns success result. For example:

```
▶ rubocop
Inspecting 38 files
......................................

38 files inspected, no offenses detected
```

To enable necessary cop, you should just set `Enable: true` for cop:

```
# .rubocop.yml

AllCops:
  DisabledByDefault: true

Metrics/MethodLength:
  Enabled: true
```

Result:

```
▶ rubocop
Inspecting 38 files
.......................C...C..........

Offenses:

# your offenses description

38 files inspected, 2 offenses detected
```